# Add a 3D layer on a Google Maps object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, 3d, google-maps-drawing

I want to add a 3D layer showing cloud location and elevation on a Google Maps.

The idea is that when you tilt the map (ctrl+drag in Earth mode) you could see how high each cloud is.

I found this article which explains how to add 3D buildings but it's "fakes", cheating with the latitudes to get some height effect:

http://johndyer.name/drawing-3d-objects-and-building-on-google-maps/

[image: 3d layer]

I couldn't find anything up to date in the doc.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099416/using-3d-in-google-maps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google seems to be silent about 3D features in Javascript API. Closest I can get to this are Styled Maps but nowhere does it specifically indicate 3D. Only [Android implementations](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#introduction) are available as of now.

I did some research and found this library which help you build 2D and 3D: https://github.com/OSMBuildings/OSMBuildings

Comment: Is it allowed by Google policy? The question need to be answered first. If you know the answer please do answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092096/is-it-allowed-to-render-3d-objects-on-top-of-google-maps

Comment: @rantiev your question was moderated/ voted to negative 1.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is Cesium JS:

> An open-source JavaScript library for world-class 3D globes and maps
>
> https://cesiumjs.org/